# Can I use haskell platform with GHC 7.4.2?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

While trying to compile, [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) (2012.2.0.0) I realized I compiled the wrong [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) (I downloaded 7.4.2 instead of 7.4.1).

Are there any problems with using 7.4.2 with haskell-platform, especially on production server, or should I install 7.4.1?

Comment: and just a note, if you're deploying on AWS and have a choice of OS: folks maintaining haskell packages on debian do a great job, so I'd recommend debian testing if you don't want to compile the haskell platform yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if debian is available as a free-tier option. Amazon Linux AMI is however, so I'm trying to compile it now.

Comment: @jberryman Oh, nvm! I just realized they have Ubuntu 12.04 as part of free-tier program. I'll try that - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will probably "just work", since GHC minor releases don't break API compatibility.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't... it's not finding something called `hscolour`. Looks just like this bug: http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/ticket/160

Comment: @drozzy You should be able to install hscolour with a bare GHC (+cabal-install if you want it easy), though. It depends only on base and containers.